# Query latest votes per user per post in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a voting system where a user can vote up or down on a post. The votes will be used in a calculation, so I need to store them in a log format, ie, I am saving each vote in it's own table.

Something like this:

```
class PointLog(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, db_index=True)
    points = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    data = models.IntegerField()  # -1, 0 or 1
```

Now I need to display 20 Posts, together with the last vote the user did.

I am using `django-rest-framework`, so I can use a serializer field that looks like this; `uservote = serializers.SerializerMethodField()`, together with a function like:

```
def get_uservote(self, obj):
    user = self.context['request'].user
    vote = PointLog.objects.only('data').filter(user=user, post=obj).last()
    return vote.data if vote else 0
```

But that will do a db-query 1 time per post, which I hope there is a better solution for.

I could save a db-query for each time the get_uservote is ran by saving the queryset in self.context, so that part is covered.
But how can I do a query that based on a list of items returns all the `latest` data from another table.

A start would be `PointLog.objects.filter(user=user, post__in=posts)`, but what next? Is this even possible using raw SQL in 1 query?

**Update 1**:
`PointLog.objects.filter(...).order_by('post__id').distinct('post__id')` would kinda do it, except that I don't think I am guaranteed to get the `newest` vote. If I use order_by('pk') (or 'time'), I can't use `distinct('post__id')` as I will get an sql error (`ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that only added 1 extra query.

The full `get_uservote` that works would be;

```
def get_uservote(self, obj):
    user = self.context['request'].user
    if user.is_authenticated():
        if not self.context.get('get_uservote_data'):
            self.context['get_uservote_data'] = {i.post_id: i.data for i in PointLog.objects.filter(user=user, post__in=self.instance).order_by('post__id', '-pk').distinct('post__id')}
        return self.context['get_uservote_data'].get(obj.id, 0)
    else:
        return 0  # Return 0 as "not voted" if not logged in
```

Note that we are doing a couple of tricks here;

- Storing the data in `self.context['get_uservote_data']` so we only haveto run the query one time.
- Using `i.post_id` as the key for our data, and not `i.post.id`. Asking for `i.post.id` here would trigger 1 query per item.
- `self.instance` is the queryset with all the posts we want to filter on.

This all resulted in a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("post_pointlog"."post_id") "post_pointlog"."id",
                                               "post_pointlog"."post_id",
                                               "post_pointlog"."data"
FROM   "post_pointlog"
WHERE  ( "post_pointlog"."user_id" = 20
         AND "post_pointlog"."post_id" IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) )
ORDER  BY "post_pointlog"."post_id" ASC,
          "post_pointlog"."id" DESC
```